# Is it possible to make bootstrap column "snap" into place?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am playing around with Bootstrap and I ran into a small problem that I can't find a solution for. There probably is a solution out there, but I can't, for the life of me, figure out what to search for.

What I want to know is, if there is a way to make the columns snap to each other, so a big gap doesn't show up like shown in the fiddle, below the first div on the left hand side. I hope the fiddle describes the problem well enough for someone to point me in the right direction.

[image: a big gap]

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/24238/

```css
body {
  background: tomato;
}
.container {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 container">
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
    <div class="media-container">
      <a href="http://placehold.it/200x200">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
      </a>
      <a href="http://placehold.it/200x200">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
      </a>
      <a href="http://placehold.it/200x200">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
      </a>
      <a href="http://placehold.it/200x200">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
      </a>
      <a href="http://placehold.it/200x200">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6 container">
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
    <div class="media-container">
      <a href="http://placehold.it/200x200">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
      </a>
      <a href="http://placehold.it/200x200">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
      </a>
      <a href="http://placehold.it/200x200">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6 container">
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
    <div class="media-container">
      <a href="http://placehold.it/200x200">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
      </a>
      <a href="http://placehold.it/200x200">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
      </a>
      <a href="http://placehold.it/200x200">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6 container">
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
    <div class="media-container">
      <a href="http://placehold.it/200x200">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
      </a>
      <a href="http://placehold.it/200x200">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
      </a>
      <a href="http://placehold.it/200x200">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6 container">
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
    <div class="media-container">
      <a href="http://placehold.it/200x200">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
      </a>
      <a href="http://placehold.it/200x200">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
      </a>
      <a href="http://placehold.it/200x200">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6 container">
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
    <div class="media-container">
      <a href="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
      </a>
      <a href="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
      </a>
      <a href="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you looking for a masonry-type (http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html) thing?

Comment: Can you tell us more about the "big gap"? The fiddle looks pretty standard to me. There's a title, some content and a separator.

Comment: @rns - I will take a look at that, looks like something I could use! However, I would love if Bootstrap offers something like that. I don't need all the fancy animation, just for it to sort itself out the way it does.

Comment: @Lazar Ljubenović - Try opening the fiddle instead of running it here. I noticed that it looks different when you run the snippet, compared to what it looks like on jsfiddle.net

Comment: Seems unclear to me .... where the problem is

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the issue: http://imgur.com/a/V1wrZ

Comment: So the issue is visible only on large screens. You cannot fix it simply if you don't know the height of the containers. You need something like rsn offered above.

Comment: "container" is a bootrap class. You shouldnt add it to the cols

Comment: @user1655756 - Yeah, that's true. I just named it container for the example, didn't think about the Bootstrap conflict. I am not using the same name in the actual project.

Comment: @Lazar Ljubenović Alright. I will have a look at it and see if I can use it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Problem in your bootstrap grid structure. You use "container" class under "ROW" & "COL-MD-" so that's why you face the problem.

```
Working fiddle:   https://jsfiddle.net/amitmonsterme/veyq6naL/ 

view this tutorial :   http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the `float: right` property to particular blocks when the screen width becomes `992px` or more. I've defined a new special class `.pull-md-right` for this purpose.

Please check the result: https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/9dqsj4pk/

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

body {
    background: tomato;
}

.container {
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .pull-md-right {
    float: right !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
          <h3>Title 1</h3>
          <p>Paragraph</p>
          <div class="media-container">
              <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"></a>
              <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"></a>
              <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"></a>
              <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"></a>
              <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"></a>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
          <h3>Title 2</h3>
          <p>Paragraph</p>
          <div class="media-container">
              <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"></a>
              <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"></a>
              <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"></a>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6 pull-md-right">
          <h3>Title 3</h3>
          <p>Paragraph</p>
          <div class="media-container">
              <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"></a>
              <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"></a>
              <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"></a>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
          <h3>Title 4</h3>
          <p>Paragraph</p>
          <div class="media-container">
              <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"></a>
              <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"></a>
              <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"></a>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6 pull-md-right">
          <h3>Title 5</h3>
          <p>Paragraph</p>
          <div class="media-container">
              <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"></a>
              <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"></a>
              <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"></a>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
          <h3>Title 6</h3>
          <p>Paragraph</p>
          <div class="media-container">
              <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"></a>
              <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"></a>
              <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"></a>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```